# Setting drop down menu Position (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place the dropdown menu right after the yellow border. With current code, menu cover product button, so I need it to be displayed at the red of product. As can be seen on "Click Me" button.

**The Code:**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.menu {
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.dropdown:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dropdown web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="w3style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contect Us</li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <li>
          <a class="button" href="#">Products</a> 
        </li>
        <div class="menu">
          <a href="#">01</a>
          <a href="#">02</a>
          <a href="#">03</a>
          <a href="#">04</a>
          <a href="#">05</a>
          <a href="#">06</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="button">Click Me</button>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#"> Link 01 </a>
        <a href="#"> Link 02 </a>
        <a href="#"> Link 03 </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Only `li` are permitted children of a `ul`

Comment: When you ask a question, press Ctrl+M in the question editor and put your code into the appropriate boxes (ala jsFiddle). No need to add the stack snippet comments manually.

Comment: Interesting.

My correction was exactly the same as you checked as true answer.

However, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct the HTML (*which is currently invalid*) as only `li` are permitted children of a `ul`.

Then a different clearing mthod so the dropdown can appear outside the parent `ul`.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VaQRoj)

```css
.cf:after { /* clearfix */
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative; /* positioning context */
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.menu {
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.dropdown:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cf">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contect Us</li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="button" href="#">Products</a>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#">01</a>
      <a href="#">02</a>
      <a href="#">03</a>
      <a href="#">04</a>
      <a href="#">05</a>
      <a href="#">06</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, great stuff but little complex. :)

Comment: It's also the correct method. All the others are ***invalid*** HTML. You can't mix `li` and `div`...only `li` are allowed as direct children of `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the height of these two buttons are different, so with adding some `style` you can solve that.
This can be one possible solution for your problem:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.menu {
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu a {
  padding-top: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.dropdown:hover .menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 54px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contect Us</li>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <li> <a class="button" href="#">Products</a>
    </li>

    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#">01</a>
      <a href="#">02</a>
      <a href="#">03</a>
      <a href="#">04</a>
      <a href="#">05</a>
      <a href="#">06</a>

    </div>

  </div>
</ul>


<div class="dropdown">

  <button class="button">Click Me</button>

  <div class="menu" style="margin-top: 0px">
    <a href="#"> Link 01 </a>
    <a href="#"> Link 02 </a>
    <a href="#"> Link 03 </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/99kym9km/)